# X-Window can not distinguish between left and right buttons

Tags: keyboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-windows, alt

I installed Windows Subsystem for Linux and Debian on my MS Windows 10.
In the console, switching languages(English <-> C/J/K) works well using Right Alt key.

But, in the X environment, I cannot switch languages. I checked key code using xev. Surprisingly, I found that the codes for the left and right Alt keys were the same. It was not just Alt keys, but Ctrl and Shift keys as well.

What can I do to fix it?

I use XLaunch(VcxSrv) and xfce4 for X.

Comment: Haven't tried this on WSL, but if you use `evtest` on whatever virtual device WSL probably has, do you also get the same codes?

Comment: @dirkt: the vcxsrv X server here seems to be the kind that runs natively as a Win32 app and just translates Windows key codes to X11 key codes. So I doubt /dev/input would be relevant... in fact I doubt it even exists on WSL.

Comment: @grawity: /dev/input not exists.

Comment: So then you know where to look next: Does vcxsrv translate the Windows key codes correctly, or does it jumble left and right modifiers together?